# How does Spark writestream know that something new has arrived in the input stream and now it has to write?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to streaming and have this confusion following the documentation. I am not getting the flow of how writestream automatically writes into the console if something new has arrived. Does it waits in the background for inputstream to read something new or does the writestream still writes null even if nothing has arrived? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#overview

```scala
//From doc
// Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to localhost:9999
val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", "localhost")
  .option("port", 9999)
  .load()

// Split the lines into words
val words = lines.as[String].flatMap(_.split(" "))

// Generate running word count
val wordCounts = words.groupBy("value").count()

// Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
val query = wordCounts.writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

And from the doc, the result table is updated, is it so that everytime a new result table is created or the values of the table are updated after word count query?

Answer (score 0):

When a streaming query is started (`DataStreamWriter.start`), a new stream execution thread is started. That thread is either of `ContinuousExecution` or `MicroBatchExecution` stream processing engines (based on trigger).

Let's focus on `MicroBatchExecution` only.

### Micro-Batch Stream Processing Engine

Every trigger executes a series of phases (*steps*) that all together are a single streaming batch.

Among the phases is **getOffset** that queries the sources for their current offsets. If the offsets are different than what the engine knows, that can only mean that there are records to be processed and so the following phases are executed, incl. **addBatch** phase that adds the current batch of records (as `Dataset`) to the sink.

That cycle happens every trigger.